# How to add a field and sort with the results on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to find all customer in my collection that have firstName LastName and Address fields as not nulls (they should exist) and then I want to create a 'confirmed' field on the fly to sort them (like all true together and all false together) ascending or descending . How would I make this query with mongodb , is this even possible ?

Comment: Existance can be checked with the `$exists` key.  Such as `{ 'firstName': { $exists: true } }`

Comment: Regarding the `confirmed` field, how would you generate the true/false of that on the fly?

Comment: the idea is that , if all 3 conditions are true then is confirmed and the same with false

Comment: Well, if your criteria is only pulling back those that have all three existing, when would it ever be false?

Comment: if that document doesn't have one of those properties or is undefined then it would be false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $addFields: {
        confirmed: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                { $eq: [ { $type: "$firstName" }, "string" ] },
                { $eq: [ { $type: "$lastName" }, "string" ] },
                { $eq: [ { $type: "$address" }, "string" ] } // If address is of type `object`, change `string` to `object`.
              ]
            },
            true,
            false
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: { confirmed: -1 }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uO4x6CCZ2Ly)

**Note :**

As we're checking against type it would check for field existence & not equals to `null` but not other false values like `" " or 0`.